# R function also returning NULL

Tags: r

Recently I started looking into R and trying to replicate some of my python projects. 
For example, I have two vectors:

```
k = c(1,2,3,4,11,23,24,25,26)
l = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11)
```

And the function:

```
test_function <- function(b) {
  if (b %in% l) {
    return(b)
}
```

After running the function

```
sapply(k, test_function)
```

it returns also NULL

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 11

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL
```

Why does it return NULL? Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: Because you didn't specify what to return `if` it is not TRUE i.e. there is only `if` condition and not `else`

Comment: Thanks. I want to return only values when condition is met. Which operation should I use in the else statement?

Comment: In that case, `Filter(test_function, k)`

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that, at least for this example code, `k[k %in% l]` or `intersect(k, l)` accomplishes the same effect, but returns the result as a vector, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = c(1,2,3,4,11,23,24,25,26)
l = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,11)
```

I'm guessing that you actually were hoping for a test of each element of `k` being found inside `l`:

```
k[ sapply(k, `%in%`, l) ]  # inner result is logical vector used to select items
#[1]  1  2  3  4 11
```

The `if` function is not appropriate for testing multiple conditions all by itself, but I guess you suspected that. The `sapply` function returns a list with a value for every item passed, and then because there are NULLs in the result, it is unable to simplify. R does not consider a NULL to be the same as an NA. If you had constructed `test_function` so that an NA was retruned when an item was not in the tested vector then sapply would have been able to simplify:

```
 test_function2 <- function(b) {
   if (b %in% l) {
     return(b)
 } else{NA} }
 sapply( k, test_function2)
#[1]  1  2  3  4 11 NA NA NA NA
```

I see comments that mention `intersect`, also a good function to remember when doing set comparisons. Then there is also `match`:

```
k[ match(l,k)]   # match returns position indexing
[1]  1  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA 11
```